# Instagram video cut slider

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-seekbar

So I come across a very interesting effect that I would also like to have in my application: Video crop slider from Instagram. For those who hasn't seen it yet, here's a gif I made.

[image]

You can also slide the images that is highlighted to the right or the left, but I didn't include it in the gif.

I included a `horizontal listview` from [here](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView), and also a `seekbar` in the same place, but it was impossible to scroll listview under the `seekbar` and vice vera.

Have you guys any idea how to do this? Any answer and comment is greatly appreciated.